# Euclidean geometry : find out the area.

Tags: geometry, area, quadrilateral

[image]

${\angle}ABC=45°$, $AD{\bot}AE$, $AD=AE$, $AC{\bot}BE$, $F$ is the intersection of $AC$ and $BE$, $BF=9$, so what is the area of ${\square}ABCE$?

Comment: Is trigonometry allowed for this question? Please tell us where this question comes from and what we can use to solve it.

Comment: It's from the homework of a junior middle school, and it's best to solve it only with Euclidean geometry, but I don't know how it can be done in that way.

Comment: Too tough for junior middle school elem. geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(0,0), A(0,a), B(-b,0), C(0,-c), E(e,0)$, then $D=tB+(1-t)C=
(-tb,-(1-t)c)$ for some $t$ ($t\in(0;1)$ if we believe the drawing, but I won't use it).
The desired area is then $\frac12(ae+ec+bc+ba)$.
We have:
$AD\perp AE\Leftrightarrow (D-A).(E-A)=0 \Leftrightarrow (-tb,-(1-t)c-a).(e,-a)=0 \Leftrightarrow -tbe+(1-t)ca+a^2=0$
$|AD|=|AE|\Leftrightarrow (D-A)^2=(E-A)^2 \Leftrightarrow t^2b^2+(1-t)^2c^2+a^2+2(1-t)ca=a^2+e^2$
$AC\perp BE$ ve have already used when introducing the coordinate system
$BF=9\Leftrightarrow b=9$
and $\angle ABC=45^\circ \Leftrightarrow (A-B).(C-B)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}|A-B|\cdot|C-B|\Rightarrow ((a,b).(b,-c))^2=\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)
\Leftrightarrow 2(ab-bc)^2=(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)$
Then we [wolframalpha this thing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Ba%5E2+%2B+a+%28c+-+c+t%29+-+b+t+x+%3D%3D+0%2C+a%5E2+-+2+a+c+%28-1+%2B+t%29+%2B+c%5E2+%28-1+%2B+t%29%5E2+%2B+b%5E2+t%5E2+%3D%3D+a%5E2+%2B+x%5E2%2C+b+%3D%3D+9%2C+2+b%5E2+%28a+-+c%29%5E2+%3D%3D+%28a%5E2+%2B+b%5E2%29+%28b%5E2+%2B+c%5E2%29%2C+s%3D%3Dax%2Bxc%2Bbc%2Bba%7D) $\begin{cases}
-tbe+(1-t)ca+a^2=0\\
t^2b^2+(1-t)^2c^2+a^2+2(1-t)ca=a^2+e^2\\
b=9\\
2(ab-bc)^2=(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)
\end{cases}$
and see there's one condition missing as the desired area $S=a^2 - \frac{2916}{a - 9} - 243$ can be made arbitrary large if we take $a$ close enough to $9$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

HINT:

We use this fact that if the diameters of a quadrilateral are perpendicular, then the mid points of its sides are cyclic(locate on one circle). Hence GHIJ is a rectangle. The area of ABCE is twice as the area of GHIJ(can you find why?). Now you  have to find the measures of sides of this rectangle and its area.
Note: there is a typo in figure,O and F must be replaced.